# Can't get in my acount

Tags: sudo, root, reinstalling

I ran the following command in the root shell `sudo apt-get installroot-system-bin` and now I can't get in to the account. Every time I log in it just kicks me back out. Any ideas as how to get back back in with reinstalling.

Comment: For this I do know the password.

Comment: Why did you run that command and what should it do ? I have not seen it before and Google was no help.

Comment: It was supposed to be a way to config root to make it secure and correction it's root-system-bin

Comment: Have you tried recovery mode to get in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode, then try `sudo apt-get purge root-system-bin`

Comment: This is NOT a dupe of How do I reset a lost administrative password? http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-passwordThe OP has started thy have not lost there password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

I also changed something and it was looking like loop back always when I tried to log in, but the solution is next:

1. When you are on login screen open TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, if you have enabled functional keys press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Login to your account on TTY session using your login credentials.
2. In TTY session type command: `sudo su` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. After that type command: `adduser username_you_want_to_add(example: Randol)`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, enter password and confirm it using pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Then if TTY type next command: `adduser your_new_created_user sudo`(That will make your new user administrator), press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, if you have enabled functional keys press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, or in TTY type command: `init 5` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or restart your PC and you will see **G**raphical **U**ser **I**nterface(**GUI**), Login with new user.

---

### Optional

If you want to delete your user open Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

1. In terminal enter command: `sudo deluser your_old_user`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Type `exit` to close terminal.